# How to install software that "Requires installation of untrusted packages"?

Tags: updates

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.  When I try to update the software, it shows me this error:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
Details 
kalzium-data kanagram kate-data kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn kde-runtime-data kdegames-data klettres-data libakonadi-kabc4 liblxc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 lxc marble-data nepomuk-core-data parley-data tomboy
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't install untrusted packages using Update Manager.

Open your terminal and type

`sudo apt-get update`

You will be prompted for your password. Enter it.

Now enter the following command.

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Now it will ask you if you want to download X Mb of packages. Give yes.
Now it will list all `untrusted packages` and will ask you if you want to install. Again give yes.

Now, all your required packages should get installed.

Comment: What to do to avoid installing from those untrusted sources and only install from the trusted ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from terminal and then update from the Update Manager.

OR

Add the untrusted package and do from UI. `sudo apt-add-repository "package name"`.